# Should I use a new core version that doesn't yet have its first stable release for production?

Tags: 8

I want to start using Drupal 8.

Can I use it in its current state for a simple blog site built with  views?

Comment: I can't remember where I saw the following (paraphrased) quote (I think it was chx either on here or D.o) - but I think it's something like the following:  *"If you have to ask this question, then you shouldn't use it."*

Comment: The answer to this question would also be irrelevant, since you should use it just for testing, debugging, or providing patches. If you are developing modules, you could be interested in checking how Drupal core code is going to change, but using it in production servers is quite different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We should always prefer the latest stable release. You may know that the alpha, beta versions are not completed so after all the issues are fixed & testing everything the author will update the stable release. Once we got the stable release then we can update our site later.

Answer (score 9):

The real question is: what's the Drupal core lifecycle look like?

First, we have feature thaw. During this time it's really a bad idea to even try to build anything on it. It's likely to be broken, buggy, and so on. (Although now we have extensive test coverage so it's less broken than you'd think.)

Then there's a feature freeze. People with some knowledge, patience and not too important sites -- say, a blog :) -- could start testing. It'd be great if this happened. You need to understand that there is still no guarantee that your data can stay intact from one git pull to the next. (This is where we are now.)

The next step is beta. From beta and on we support upgrades. So while it's not the quality you'd expect from a released product, it's time to begin serious testing. If you start testing when release happened, your problems will take a lot longer to be fixed.